# Adding percentage button to javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am working on a calculator program to practice and aid in learning javascript. I have this so far:

```js
<!DOCtype html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd XHTML 1.0 transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/Dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type" />
<title>Calculator</title>
<h1><center>On-Line Calculator</center></h1>
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
function addChar(input, character) {
 if(input.value == null || input.value == "0")
  input.value = character
 else
  input.value += character
}

function sqrt(form) {
 form.display.value = Math.sqrt(form.display.value);
}

function changeSign(input) {
 if(input.value.substring(0, 1) == "-")
  input.value = input.value.substring(1, input.value.length)
 else
  input.value = "-" + input.value
}

function compute(form) {
 form.display.value = eval(form.display.value)
}

function checkNum(str) {
 for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  var ch = str.substring(i, i+1)
  if (ch < "0" || ch > "9") {
   if (ch != "/" && ch != "*" && ch != "+" && ch != "-" && ch != "."
    && ch != "(" && ch!= ")") {
    alert("invalid entry!")
    return false
    }
   }
  }
  return true
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="sci-calc">
  <table  border="2"CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="5" align="center" >
  <tr>
   <td COLSPAN="3" align="center"><input name="display" value="0" SIZE="28" MAXLENGTH="25"></td>
   <td align="center" colspan="1" ><input type="button" value="  %  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '%')" style="width: 135px"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="center" colspan="1" ><input type="button" value="  7  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '7')" style="width: 135px"></td>
   <td align="center" colspan="1" ><input type="button" value="  8  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '8')" style="width: 136px" ></td>
   <td align="center"colspan="1"><input type="button" value="  9  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '9')" style="width: 135px" ></td>
   <td align="center"colspan="1"><input type="button" value="   +  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '+')" style="width: 137px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="center"colspan="1"><input type="button" value="  4  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '4')" style="width: 133px"></td>
   <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="button" value="  5  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '5')" style="width: 131px"></td>
   <td align="center"colspan="1"><input type="button" value="  6  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '6')" style="width: 134px"></td>
   <td align="center"colspan="1"><input type="button" value="   -   " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '-')" style="width: 139px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="center"colspan="1" ><input type="button" value="  1  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '1')" style="width: 133px"></td>
   <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="button" value="  2  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '2')" style="width: 128px"></td>
   <td align="center"colspan="1"><input type="button" value="  3  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '3')" style="width: 132px"></td>
   <td align="center"colspan="1"><input type="button" value="   *   " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '*')" style="width: 137px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="center"colspan="1"><input type="button" value="  0  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '0')" style="width: 131px"></td>
   <td align="center" ><input type="button" value="   .  " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '.')" style="width: 129px"></td>
   <td align="center"><input type="button" value=" sqrt " ONCLICK="if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) { sqrt(this.form) }" style="width: 136px"></td>
   <td align="center"><input type="button" value="   /   " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '/')" style="width: 139px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="center" ><input type="button" value="    (    " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, '(')" style="width: 131px"></td>
   <td align="center" ><input type="button" value="   )   " ONCLICK="addChar(this.form.display, ')')" style="width: 132px"></td>
   <td align="center" ><input type="button" value="=" name="enter" ONCLICK="if (checkNum(this.form.display.value)) { compute(this.form) }" style="width: 141px"></td>
   <td align="center" ><input type="button" value="clear" ONCLICK="this.form.display.value = 0 " style="width: 141px"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</html>
```

I have a couple questions:

1. I need a working percentage button, the one I have now does not do what I need it to do. It should display what precent the first input number is of the second. I.e. if the first number is 5 and the second is 20, then the result should be 25 (meaning 25 %).
2. I need to display all the operations entered, not only the results of the calculations performed by the user. For example, on 3+4, instead of just displaying "7", display "3 + 4 = 7". Keep the display of all previous calculations in the input field, instead of just the current one.

Can someone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: I assume your percentage calculation doesn't work because the equation `5 % 20` reads as `five modulo twenty`. For the latter, just either record every input into a variable, or extract it from the input field using `.value` (if the math should be visible, it is currently not).

Answer (score 0):

The calculator above doesn't seem to work for me.
However, I can make a couple of suggestions that think will help you a long the way.

A) Please don't take this the wrong way.  Part of programming is resolving the issues that you are having -- that is the fun of it.  Gets more fun when your under pressure of deadlines.

B) I would recommend using jQuery.  You will inherently learn javascript.

C) Finally, use div tags to write the validated key press to read from that separating the values by operators.

eg:

```
calculation=$('#output_div_id').val();
calculation_parts = calculation.split('+');
answer = parseInt(calculation_part[0]) + parseInt(calculation_part[1]).

$('#output_div_id').html($('#output_div_id').html()+ "=" + answer);
```

Hope that helps - good luck with learning java